# Variable Python3_LINK_OPTIONS from cmake is empty

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, build, portability

I am trying to use the variable `Python3_LINK_OPTIONS` from the [FindPython3](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython3.html) module of cmake. However, on all my machines this is empty. I tried different OS (ubuntu, macos, windows) with different versions of cmake all with the same result.

What am I doing wrong or is this variable not properly supported? My minimal CMakeLists.txt test looks like this but it's not giving me the expected result:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(test)

find_package(Python3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)
message("${Python3_LINK_OPTIONS}")
```

Comment: The variable `Python3_LINK_OPTIONS` is just empty on configurations where you have tried. It is noted in its description: "**Some configurations** require specific link options for a correct build and execution."